# Given a string, determine if it is a palindrome, considering only alphanumeric characters and ignoring cases

Tags: java, palindrome

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        String str = s.toLowerCase();
        int count = 0;
        boolean isfalse = true;
      char arr[] = new char[str.length()];
        for(int i = 0;i<str.length();){
            if(!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))){
                i++;
            }else{
                arr[count] = str.charAt(i);
                count++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            int j = arr.length-count;
            if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
                isfalse = true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me why my code isn't working or if it will work with an array or not.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "It isn't working" is not a meaningful problem statement. Please [edit] your question to include the details of *how* your program isn't working, including any errors, expected vs actual behavior, etc.

Comment: What is input you are testing with?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever happens your code will always return false. Since you aren't using the defined variable `isFalse` as a `return` statement. I took your code modified the last part i.e. your for loop and converted to while loop to check equality from both side, using double pointer technique. Now it looks something like below.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    String str = s.toLowerCase();
    int count = 0;
    char arr[] = new char[str.length()];
    for(int i = 0;i<str.length();){
        if(!Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
            i++;
        }else{
            arr[count] = str.charAt(i);
            count++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = count - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        System.out.println(arr[i] + " : " + arr[j]);
        if (arr[i] != arr[j])
            return false;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Try adding these to your code and it should work.

Comment: Thank  You.It's Working for 454 cases out of 476.I think it's failing for the cases where the length of string is 2.

Comment: @KAKUOUS It's not failing for string of length 2. I just checked it. Can you provide input for which it is failing.

Comment: "0P" For this string it's failing.

Comment: @MohitSingh Your code didn't check condition for cases where string contains number. I have updated the code. It should work.

Comment: @MohitSingh: Please accept the answer, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will take the worst space complexity of `O(s)` where `s` is the length of the string:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isLetter(ch) || Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                sb.append(ch + "");
            }
        }
        
        return sb.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(sb.reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Simple Java Solution   
 class Solution {
        public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
            s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "").trim();
            s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
            String str = "";
            for (int i = s.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                str += s.charAt(i);
            }
            return s.equals(str);
        }
    }
```